# What to assume if exact lower limit data values are not available

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have some data - about 100 values, maximum value 100.

However, values below 10 are just written as <10, exact values for these are not available.

How can I impute these data points. What value should I assume these data points to have? Should I take 5 (midway between 0 and 10)? If we assume normal distribution for whole data, average of these points would be around 7 (considering tail of normal distribution curve).

Thanks for your insight.

Edit: re discussion in comments:

[image]

For a perfect triangle with base between 0 and x, mean seems to be 0.633 times x (on checking data on spreadsheet), though I do not have mathematical proof.

Comment: What are you trying to use them to do?

Comment: What percentage of values are censored, "< 10" ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico :  About 5-7% of values are below 10.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica : I have to use this data as a continuous variable for determining group differences, correlations etc.

Comment: I'd be inclined to treat the data as what it is -- left-censored data. I wouldn't try to invent data, I'd use the data as it is. For some purposes you may want to use a parametric distributional model but you still have censored data in that context.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica : If I have 2 groups, how can I apply Mann-Whitney U or unpaired t-test while not imputing these values?

Comment: Well, if you are going to use a ranked-based test like Mann-Whitney, it doesn't matter what values you give to the censored values, as long they're all less than 10 and all the same value.

Comment: @rnso I was suggesting doing something more appropriate for censored data, but Sal's suggestion would work (i.e. to treat them as tied within the <10 bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some simple approaches with censored data, see [USEPA, 2000, Guidance for Data Quality Assessment: Practical Methods for Data Analysis,EPA/600/R-96/084](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2015-06/documents/g9-final.pdf). Section 4.7. Note that this document was last revised 20 years ago.

They recommend that if less than 15% of the data is censored †, that a value of half the censored limit can be used ‡.  For larger percentages, they recommend trimmed means or categorizing data and using a test of proportions.  Among other approaches.

Also, I think it's worthwhile to think about what kind of data you have and what went into the censoring process.  This may inform the approach you take.

__

† Here, they're considering environmental data, which I presume assumes the data are non-negative, left-censored, and the censoring is done at the detection limit of the chemical/physical analysis.

‡ It worries me some that your limit of censoring (10) isn't that many orders of magnitude away from the maximum observed value (100).  Often, say with water quality data, you might have, say, a detection limit of 0.1 and a maximum of 10.  This at least gives you a couple orders of magnitude between the detection limit and the maximum of the data.  Because of this, it will often make no practical difference if the actual observed value was 0, 0.05, or 0.1.  For your data, I wonder if the difference between 0, 5, and 10 would make a difference in interpreting data.

Comment: Can there be any formula/algorithm for value to be used given maximum recorded, minimum recorded and size of data/proportion censored?

Comment: I don't know of anything like that.

Comment: Considering triangular shape of lower limit (for otherwise normally distributed data) 2/3 of lower limit rather than 1/2 may be more reasonable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If what are saying is relevant to your question, you need to provide those details in your question.

Comment: Pl see image in my question above which I have added as edit.

Comment: I see what you mean.  If you're substituting the censored values with a small value, it shouldn't much matter which you choose.  Traditionally 1/2 of the detection limit is used, but if you feel better making it 2/3 of the detection limit, it shouldn't make much difference.