# Statistical analysis on values that are not exact but above or below a limit (e.g. >100, or <5)

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics, data-imputation, censoring, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a data set with a small number of bioreplicates (3-10) per sample, and I am assessing whether each sample is statistically different from the wildtype control using a Kruskal-Wallis test with Dunn's post-hoc multiple comparisons. For some of the samples, my values were outside of the range of the assay, and so are reported as >100 or >200. I am reporting them as is but for assessing significance, I am wondering if it is possible to include them in the Kruskal-Wallis analysis, and if so, what value to use. For example, could I just replace the ">100" value for each replicate with the value of "100"? If anything, since these values are all greater than the control group (which has an average value of ~5) I would think that this approach would actually be more conservative in assessing statistical significance, as the actual values are greater than 100.

I was reading a similar thread on StackExchange (linked below) but my example differs somewhat in that there is no clear limit of detection threshold for this type of assay, and so I don't think their solution applies:

[What to assume if exact lower limit data values are not available](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440120/what-to-assume-if-exact-lower-limit-data-values-are-not-available)

I'm a bit of a stats novice so I apologize if this is a bit unclear. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: As a quick addendum, in case it's not clear, the issue for this assay is that these values actually fall outside of the upper limit, whereas I'm guessing with similar examples of this type of statistical question the issue is falling below a lower limit of detection...

Comment: I think the term of are you’re looking for is “censoring.”

Comment: Yes! I think that's right, it would be right-censored data! I'm still not sure how to handle this type of data in statistical analysis...

Comment: You want to use a rank-based procedure, but you can rank observations sometimes without knowing *exact* value! So, just replace with values that will give correct rank

Comment: A place to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics) . If you have a parametric model, dealing with censoring is a standard problem; some nonparametric approaches are in wide use for some kinds of problems. If you're looking for a rank based approach, kjetil's response makes sense.

Comment: What to do with multiple censoring limits is complicated, especially with two-sided censoring.  Perhaps the simplest approach with KW is to rank all the ">" values as tied for the highest (assuming they are all above any quantified value) and rank all the "<" values as tied for the lowest (assuming the are all below any quantified value) and test your hypothesis.  If it's significant, you're done; otherwise, you need to apply a more delicate procedure.

Comment: Thanks to everyone on this thread for the helpful insights!